# iOS App hangs when transitioning to a new scene for the first time

Tags: ios

My app is hanging for about 2 seconds when I try to transition from my 'Main Menu' scene to my 'AI Game Scene'. All animations freeze, and the app simply does nothing for a brief period of time.

Here is the code where I transition to my new scene. If you need to see any other code to diagnose the problem, I can provide it!

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        //location is where they touched
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        //the node at that location
        let selectedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if(selectedNode.name == "Play AI"){
            let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(2)

            let scene = AIGameScene(size: self.scene!.size)
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

            self.scene!.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
```

I have surrounded the following line with 'print' statements, and found that this is the line causing the hanging issue:

```
self.scene!.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

Interestingly, it only hangs during the first transition to this scene. When I finish playing my game and go back to the main menu, I can click to "Play Versus AI" again, and this time the app will not hang! Similarly, transitioning back to the main menu screen does not hang. It's only the very first time.

Comment: its probably not so much the transition thats causing it to freeze, but probably doing a lot of loading of sprites etc when the scene is presented, this is because its all happening on the main thread probably and blocking your app from doing anything else until its all done. I suggest you put a loading screen between your main menu and your game screen

Comment: @Fonix I'll look into that. Will the loading screen not hang when trying to transition to the game scene though? Does it need to be a static image as the loading screen?

Further, would it be possible to move the transition to a different thread so that the app does not hang, but does not need a loading screen?

Comment: yes the loading screen will freeze, but if you loading screen is static then that wont matter, alternatively if you need the loading screen to be animated then you would need to load your assets asynchronously, and notify the loading screen that you can transition to the game screen once its done, that may take a bit of reworking your current flow though. a static loading screen will be the easiest solution

Comment: @Fonix thanks for your help! I actually managed to work out that the hanging is caused by setting the font in my SKLabelNode... Which is confusing to me. I was getting similar hanging issues when using a custom font. Not sure what is it about fonts that seems to cause issues, but I'll just change the font after a second or something and let it be I guess.

Comment: @Fonix as a followup, I fixed it! The problem was literally caused by using a font named "Superclarendon" instead of "Superclarendon-Regular". I needed to use the specific font name. Lmao.

Comment: quite strange, maybe it has to do some kind of search for the font if the name isnt specific enough and that takes a while or something heh